# How to get routes from other location/function in react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying React Router V06, but facing a problem where ***I have been trying it below this way but every routes and page are blank.***

Code:

```
// Main App Function
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <Routes>
              <Route index strict path="/" element={<Landing />} />
      **{/* Here I want to render paths from other function*/}**
              <Route element={<AppRoutes />} />
            </Routes>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
    
    // In AppRoutes Function
    const AppRoutes = () => (
      <section className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route strict path="login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route strict path="register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </section>
    );
    
    export default AppRoutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

In app, declare the `Landing` component to be the index page, and render `AppRoutes` on a "/*" path to allow matching sub-routes.

App

```
<Router>
  <Navbar />
  <Routes>
    <Route index element={<Landing />} />
    <Route path="/*" element={<AppRoutes />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

AppRoutes

```
const AppRoutes = () => (
  <section className="container">
    <Routes>
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  </section>
);
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-routes-from-other-location-function-in-react-router-dom-v6]

Comment: Thanks, silly of me, I couldn't figure out this small problem. It's working great!